# How to call a JavaScript function from one frame to another in Chrome/Webkit with file protocol

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, frames, file-uri

I have developed an application that has a list of items in one frame; when one clicks on an item it does something in another frame (loads an image).

This used to work fine in all browsers, including Chrome 3; now it still works fine in Firefox but in recent versions of Chrome (I believe since 4) it throws this error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL (...) from frame with URL (...).
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

This is obviously a security "feature" but is it possible to get around it?

Here is a simple test:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <frameset cols="50%,50%">
    <frame src="left.html" name="left"/>
    <frame src="right.html" name="right"/>
    </frameset>
  </html>
```

left.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:parent.right.test('hello');">click me</a>
    </body>
  </html>
```

right.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function test(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The above works in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 3 but in Chrome 5 it throws the above error...

**Edit**:

- added the @cols attribute to the frameset element
- in fact it works in Chrome if and only if the pages are served with the http protocol (and from the same domain) but **my problem is when pages are local and served from a file:// protocol**. Then it works in Firefox (all versions) and Chrome 3 but not Chrome 5 (I don't have Chrome 4 so I'm not shure about that specific version (and don't know if it's even possible to download a specific Chrome version?) -- but for Chrome 5 I'm very sure it doesn't work).

Comment: This should work fine if all pages are on the same domain. Are you 100% sure it's the same domain (not even `www.domainname` versus `domainname`)? The same protocol (http/https)?

Comment: In fact the problem is specific to the file protocol; when files are served over http and the same domain, there is no problem in Chrome; but over file:// Chrome 5 throws the error as mentioned.

The whole point of this application is to require no installation whatsoever from the user who should be able to browse the files directly on a CD-Rom (don't ask! ;-) so if the file protocol is broken that's a problem... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answers to the closely-related question: [Call a JavaScript function defined in an iframe in Chrome using the file protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111306/call-a-javascript-function-defined-in-an-iframe-in-chrome-using-the-file-protocol).

Briefly, launching Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` "solves" the problem insofar as the error will not be reported.

Of course, since you're distributing files on a CD, you're unlikely to view this an actual solution. I recommend starring [Chromium bug 47416](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416) to encourage the developers of Chromium to bring Chrome more into line with the behavior of Gecko.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your test pages, and they work fine with Chrome 4.1.249.1045 on Windows (and Firefox 3.6.3, and IE7 *[after fixing the issue below]*). So I'm with Pekka (as usual): I think the problem must lie elsewhere.

It wasn't working in IE7 and it took me forever to figure out why not: You need to give either `rows` or `cols` on the `frameset` tag, otherwise IE only loads the one frame. (The [validator](http://validator.w3.org) would have told me that if I'd asked it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for that; please see my edit of the question: in fact the problem I have with Chrome arises only when using the file protocol (not when the files are served with a webserver over http).